# Why Redirect 127.0.0.1:8000 when logging in to the django application with twitter account?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, authentication, twitter

I am about to make Django application available for production.
However, login using twitter account does not work.
I am using python-social-auth.
There should be no problem in setting.
But after being authenticated on twitter, it will be redirected to 127.0.0.1 instead of the domain I set up.

The twitter application settings are as follows.

```
Callback URL: http://example.com/
Callback URL Locked: No
Sign in with Twitter: Yes
```

the login button is as follows

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='{% url 'social:begin' 'twitter' %}'">Login</button>
```

urls.py of the django project is as follows

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin, auth

import app.urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('social_django.urls', namespace = 'social')),
    url(r'', include(app.urls)),
]
```

urls.py of app is as follows.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from app import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^home/', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name': 'logout.html'}, name='logout')
]
```

I can log in without problems in the local environment.

What is wrong?

Comment: In your twitter apps setting page Did you changed callback url ? to the actual domain ?

Comment: @RajaSimon Yes. setting up an actual domain.

Comment: Okay now redirect to your `127...` or the domain?

Comment: @RajaSimon 
When logging in with twitter account, it will still be redirected to `127 ...`.